# How do 3d engines decide where polygons go in a model?

Tags: graphics, 3d

I am trying to build my own 3d engine from a 2d one. so far everything works fine but its very inefficient due to the fact that the wire frame model has lines between every point on the shape. I've been doing some research but haven't been able to find anything regarding what dictates where polygons go for the most optimal rendering.

Here is what a cube looks like in my program:
[image: wire frame cube]

Is there some mathematical way to remove all the extra geometry?

Any advice really helps, thanks.

Comment: One simple thing would be to look at the normals of each triangle.  If they are negative, the polygon is back-facing and probably should not be visible.  After that, you can render back to front based on the "z" position of each polygon.  May not be perfect, but that should allow closer objects to be drawn on top of further ones and get you the picture you want.

Comment: One more note - a cube should be rendered as 12 triangles - 2 per face to form the 6 squares.  Right now, by connecting all vertices and making triangles that way, you are drawing 4 per face, not to mention all the internal ones that just don't matter.  Get your system to work with 12 triangles and the work gets easier.

Comment: Is there any way to assign two triangles per face automatically. Because in the future I would like to create shapes with more complex geometry and I don't want to have to assign all the triangles by hand

Comment: Given just vertices?  A 3D model is generally constructed of triangle (or other polygons), not just vertices.  Just vertices is not quite enough information to make a cube.

Comment: Again, if you rendered all your formed triangles back to front, ignoring back facing ones, you would at least see a 2D image of your cube.  If you added basic lighting to the triangles, then the 3D-ness of that image would show as well.

Comment: ok, I added code to display the 12 triangles, and added back to front rendering but there's one small problem. given just the Z axis, the program skipped over some faces, especially when rendering more complex geometry. it may just be the way i implemented it, but i've now had around 5 or six different solutions all result in the same problem

Comment: https://ibb.co/Z8q3mF7 here's an example of a face not being rendered properly

Comment: Be sure that you are going clockwise or counter clockwise along each set of vertices or your front or back facing algorithm won't work.  You have to be consistant in direction for all rendered polys

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling

Comment: http://www.dillonbhuff.com/?p=30

Comment: the way my code works is it reads vertices and triangles from a.obj file that I exported from blender. I've looked at the points and all of them move in a uniform direction. maybe there's something with .obj form blender that is messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after longer than I'd like to to admit I figured out that you don't need to order faces by their z coordinate, instead just take the surface normal of the shape and render only render it if it's above a value (most of the time 0) (also you'll want to use premade triangles from object files instead of assigning them to the faces yourself)